# Https does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, https

I'm having issues with feeding API data into my web app and Visual Studio is not recognize https.
It's an ASP.net MVC project. Just wondering if there is a better way to do this.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using pdrake.Models.MoviesData;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http.Properties;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace pdrake.Controllers.MoviesController
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MovieApiController : ControllerBase
    {
        HttpClient baseUrl = https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=My_Key;
        public HttpClient GetMovies()
        {
            return baseUrl + &language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_video=true&page=1;
        }
}
```

Comment: Also I forgot to ask about the return statement as that is returning an error. Is there a better way to do that.

Comment: This code indicates you should spend some time understanding the basics of c# programming. Is `baseUrl` meant to be a string? What information is `GetMovies` actually meant to be returning?

Comment: My Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace pdrake.Controllers.MoviesController
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MovieApiController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetMovies()
        {
            string bs = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=My_Key";
            string url = bs + "&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_video=true&page=1";

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) " +
                                                    "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) " +
                                                    "Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36");

                var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(url));

                return Ok(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is `UnAuthorised 401` which is normal (`you should provide valid credentials in the header`)

[image: Result]

***Additionally,*** I recommend you make a helper service (layer/repository/provider) that consumes the service as this is not the responsibility of the Controller.